# OAuth2 Access token deletion from database

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am trying to implement OAuth2 for a REST API which will support mobile, desktop and web apps.

I have read [Chapter 6. Refreshing an Access Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-47) of [Hardt, D., Ed., "The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework", RFC 6749, DOI 10.17487/RFC6749, October 2012](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6749)

According to RFC, access tokens and refresh tokens are saved into DB and I am doing so using MySQL.

My question is at which point/activity of OAuth2 should I remove all expired access tokens and refresh tokens.

Should I run cron job for that?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable use case for the built-in [MySQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have gone through over the doc for while and I have to read about it though seems difficult to me. :P

Answer (score 1):

> I have to read about it though seems difficult to me

Verify that the [MySQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) is enabled on the server.  If not, enable it.

Assuming the table is called "token" and it has a column called "expires_at" and that column has an index on it, and then [create a scheduled event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) with a query like this:

```
CREATE EVENT purge_expired_tokens
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE
  DO DELETE FROM token WHERE expires_at < NOW();
```

Every 15 minutes from the time you originally defined the event, the server will run that query in the background and purge any expired sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should periodically run a program that deletes expired access tokens, refresh tokens and authorization codes.